# How to repeat commands to a Python server with sockets?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am stuck on a project I am trying to work with. Right now I am trying to setup a script (this one) to open a port on local machine that will give me access to running commands on it. I am using Netcat to connect to it. Right now it will allow me to connect with netcat and then I can type in 1 command and it will give me the output and stop. When I move "conn, addr = s.accept()" outside of the while loop, I am able to run commands over and over and work like it should on some. But when I try to run a "cd .." to go back a directory, it won't let me. I was not sure if I am missing something.

```
host = ''
port = 12345
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print("Socket has been created.")

try:
    s.bind((host, port))
except socket.error:
    print("Bind failed.")
    sys.exit()

print("Socket bind complete.")

s.listen(5)
print("Socket is now listening.")

while 1:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print("Connected with {0}:{1}".format(addr[0], addr[1]))
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    string_data = data.decode('utf-8')

    proc = subprocess.Popen(string_data, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout_value = proc.stdout.read() + proc.stderr.read()
    conn.sendall(stdout_value)

    #conn.close()
    #s.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why `cd ..` doesn't work is that `cd` is a shell internal that changes the current working directory (CWD) of the shell and that only effects that shell process. As you start a shell for each command the CWD from the last shell has no effect on the next shell.

Either start the shell once and talk to it. This is what telnet and ssh do. Or keep track of the CWD yourself and process `cd` without invoking the shell. Another option is to wrap every command and have each print `$CWD` to your program and then pass that value to the next shell by the `cwd=` option of the `subprocess.Popen` function.

Comment: I would like to start the shell once and talk to it. However not sure how to do this. Any tips that can put me in the right direction?